# getchildat in viewpager is not working properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a **viewpager** with 3 views. Inside **onTouchEvent** of viewpager I try the following

```
    nextView=viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xValue = event.getX();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if((xValue-event.getX())>0) {
                float translation=(-width/2)+((xValue-event.getX())/2);
                nextView.setTranslationX(translation);
            }
        break;
    }
```

When i swipe from View1 to View3 everything works properly. But when I swipe back from View3 to View1 and back from View1 to View3 the **getChildAt** is not returning the next view. It is returning the current visible view.

How to get the next view of currently visible view. Thanks in advance. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrongly used **addView**. Initially I used

```
((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
```

getChildAt worked properly after making it like

(`(ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, position);`